# Keycloak Refresh token not of type Offline

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, access-token, bearer-token, keycloak-services

I am new to Identity management and user management in keycloak.

I am trying to generate offline refresh token. I am using keycloak 12.0.1
I have created a client in ldap-demo realm and have made sure that offline_access is added in scope by default. This curl command gives me the bearer token as well as refresh token. Now when I check the refresh token in jwt.io then its "typ" is not as "offline" but it is refresh only. I have also defined a user and role has offline_access defined by default.

```
refresh_token=`curl \
-d "client_id=ldap-app" -d "client_secret=password" \
-d "username=user1" -d "password=password" \
-d "grant_type=password"  \
-d "scope=offline_access"  \
https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ldap-demo/protocol/openid-connect/token  | jq -r '.refresh_token'`
```

Please suggest what all realm level configuration or client level configuration I need to do in keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

The refresh token format is vendor specific and you can't determine behavior by looking at it.

The offline_access scope will be present in the access token, and if it is a JWT you will be able to view this scope in it.

The thing to test is sending a refresh token grant message - you can do this via a [curl command](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens/use-refresh-tokens) or using [OAuth Tools](https://curity.io/resources/learn/test-using-oauth-tools/).

The full behavior generally works like this:

- Authorization Server (AS) - eg Keycloak - stores details of the delegation in its database
- In your case the delegation occurs when the password grant message is processed
- When you use the refresh token, details are checked against the stored state

This means the tokens returned to clients do not need to reveal full details. Eg opaque / unreadable tokens can and should be returned in some cases.